# Confidence intervals and pairwise comparisons

Tags: confidence-interval, multiple-comparisons, paired-data, paired-comparisons

Let us say I have the following pair wise test data:

```
batch        1    2    3    4   5   6   7   8   10
non-control  18   16   15   19  36  24  25  30  31
control      20   23   25   19  28  24  26  21  22
```

Each data point is measurement of some attribute X in some units

The control part of the pair share some underlying similarity to the non-control pair

The non-control part of the pair share some underlying similarity to the control pair except that is has received an exposure to say a chemical C.

Now how would I prove (or disprove) if there is strong evidence (or the lack of it) that the exposure the chemical C results in greatly increased measurements of attribute X?

How would I construct a confidence interval of the difference between the values of the con-control and control (say 90%) for the difference between attribute X between the control and non-control versions of the measurements.

This is more to further my understanding but basically I want to apply two tests:

1. Sign Test
2. Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test

Thanks.

Comment: What research have you done into the standard methods of constructing such confidence intervals? Are you having problems selecting among such tests? Or do you need help applying one of them in particular?

Comment: @whuber I update the question that I wish to apply the Sign Test and the Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test -- not sure if that helps.

Comment: @John, this is more self study

Answer (score 1):

This "R" code produces accurate results ONLY if your test is RANDOMIZED

```
rm(list=ls())
batch <- seq_len(10); batch
nonControl <- c(18,16,15,19,36,24,25,30,31)
control <- c(20,23,25,19,28,24,26,21,22)

pairedDifference <- nonControl - control; pairedDifference
pairedDifferenceMean <- mean(pairedDifference); pairedDifferenceMean
pairedDifferenceSumOfSquares <- sum((pairedDifference - pairedDifferenceMean)^2); pairedDifferenceSumOfSquares

degreesOfFreedom <- length(pairedDifference)-1; degreesOfFreedom
pairedVariance <- pairedDifferenceSumOfSquares/degreesOfFreedom; pairedVariance
pairedStandardDeviation <- sqrt(pairedVariance);pairedStandardDeviation
pairedStandardError <- pairedStandardDeviation/sqrt(degreesOfFreedom+1); pairedStandardError
```

As can be seen below:

According to the null hypothesis, the difference population mean equals zero, the reference distribution against which the observed "pairedDifferenceMean" = 0.6666667 may be viewed as a scaled t distribution with eight degrees of freedom centered at zero with a scale factor "pairedStandardError" of 2.285218. The value of "tSubZero", below, associated with the null hypothesisis:

```
tSubZero <- pairedDifferenceMean/pairedStandardError; tSubZero
significanceLevel <- 1-pt(tSubZero, df=degreesOfFreedom); significanceLevel
```